# jQuery date function returns NaN in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, date, time

I have this twitter function with makes a link with the date the tweet was posted. It works in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. IE though produces NaN or NaN days ago. The date coming into the function is formatted as such: Fri Apr 10:19:06 +0000 2012. Anyone have any thoughts?

```
            html += '<a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/' + username + '#status_' + data[i].id_str + '">' + data[i].text + ' <i>' + Twitter.daysAgo(data[i].created_at) + '</i></a>';

            daysAgo: function (date) {

            var d = new Date(date).getTime();
            var n = new Date().getTime();

            var numDays = Math.round(Math.abs(n - d) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var daysAgo = numDays + ' days ago';

            if (numDays == 0) {
                alert('Works 1');
                daysAgo = 'today';
            } else if (numDays == 1) {
                alert('Works 2');
                daysAgo = numDays + ' day ago';
            }

            return daysAgo;
```

Comment: Got mixed results in IE8. Didn't return NaN but where Chrome returned 19 days, IE8 returned 20.

Comment: Still gives me an NaN result in IE8. Any thoughts on why it's coming up with a NaN value?

Answer (score 0):

`data[i].created_at` returns a string that IE can't parse as a date. Try to format it as an ISO 8601 date string:

```
>> new Date("2012-01-01T00:00+01:00") 
Sun Jan 1 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2012
```

Note: ISO Date Format is [not supported in Internet Explorer 8 standards mode and Quirks mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Your string appears to lack the day number or have a `:` too many: `Fri Apr 10:19:06 +0000 2012`